# Change the order of indefinite integral and differential

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I want to know the sufficient condition to change the order of integral and differential.
following is the problem:

$$f \in C([0,T];L^2(R^N))$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}f=g(t,x)$$
Then we multiply $f$ on both sides and take $L^2$-innerproduct, so we get $$\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\|f\|^2_{L^2}=<g,f>.$$

In this process, I have a question in LHS.
We implicitly used the change of differential and integral operator, and I want to know why it holds.
I tried to understand it by Dominate Convergence Theorem, but I don't know how to apply it in this problem because we don't have any condition of g.
Anybody would help me please?

Comment: I'm confused about the dimensionality of the question so I can't make an answer yet, but this should be achievable through a generalization of the Leibniz integral rule

Comment: @Stephen Donovan $f=f(t,x)$ for $t\in [0,T]$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}^N$.

Comment: Okay yes that clears things up a lot. I think I can work on an answer now

Comment: @innerproduct thank you for correction!

Answer (score -1):

Starting from the left-hand side:
$$\langle g, f\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(t, x)g(t, x) dx$$ Substituting in $g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ we get
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(t,x) f_t(t,x) dx = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \partial_t \left[\frac12 f^2(t,x)\right] dx$$
Now consider the general statement of the Leibniz integral rule seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement). (apologies for referencing Wikipedia)

Restrictions $1$ and $2$ are met pretty trivially, and I believe we can say that restriction $3$ is met if the inner product between $f$ and $g$ converges, but I'm not very sure of that.

Assuming the restrictions are met, we can continue with

$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} \partial_t \left[\frac12 f^2(t,x)\right] dx = \frac12 \partial_t \int_{\mathbb R^n} f^2(t,x) dx = \frac12 \partial_t ||f||^2_{L^2}$$

Comment: Sorry, but what are the restrictions 1,2,3 you mentioned?

Comment: The theorem in the link requires three conditions of $f$ in order to transpose the derivative and integral, did you follow the link?